# question about RSA

Tags: public-key

I am very new in cryptography field, what I want to ask but I cannot find an answer is this: In public key cryptography, such as in RSA, does it matter if the adversary knows/can detect the public key? With only the public key, can he eavesdrop a message?

Thank you

Comment: Indeed in formal security definitions, the adversary is explicitly given the public key.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48423/is-it-bad-to-expose-the-public-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public key is published in public so that anyone (including attackers) can get it. The point of public-key crypto is to be able to do so without compromising security in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Public key cryptography is named **public** because public keys are considered to be available to everyone and this alone is not sufficient to decrypt messages.