# Recovery public key from secp256k1 signature and message

Tags: public-key, signature, key-recovery

Regarding this article about a [signature recovery](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/how-does-recovering-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-signature-work)

> However, with the signature and the message that was signed, and the knowledge of the curve, it is possible to generate two public keys

So we can derive 2 public keys for each signature and message

I try work with python library https://github.com/ludbb/secp256k1-py.
This library is a wrapper for C++ implementation of secp256k1. As I understand from this library we have special function sign_recoverable that returned signature with included information for recovery unique public keys. And regarding this [https://github.com/ludbb/secp256k1-py/blob/f5e455227bf1e833128adf80de8ee0ebcebf218c/secp256k1/**init**.py#L135](https://github.com/ludbb/secp256k1-py/blob/f5e455227bf1e833128adf80de8ee0ebcebf218c/secp256k1/__init__.py#L135)

```
   def ecdsa_recoverable_deserialize(self, ser_sig, rec_id):
      if not HAS_RECOVERABLE:
        raise Exception("secp256k1_recovery not enabled")
      if rec_id < 0 or rec_id > 3:
        raise Exception("invalid rec_id")
      if len(ser_sig) != 64:
        raise Exception("invalid signature length")
      recover_sig = ffi.new('secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature *')
      parsed = lib.secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature_parse_compact(
```

We have 4 variant of a possible public key from 1 signature.

In my code and attempts receive Public keys for  signature in DER format (i want to iterate all available)

```
def public_key_recovery(signature, messsage, rec_id, compressed=True, hex=True):
if isinstance(signature, str):
    signature = unhexlify(signature)
if isinstance(messsage, str):
    messsage = unhexlify(messsage)
raw_sig = ffi.new('secp256k1_ecdsa_signature *')
r = secp256k1.secp256k1_ecdsa_signature_parse_der(ECDSA_CONTEXT_VERIFY,
                                                  raw_sig,
                                                  signature,
                                                  len(signature))
if not r:
    raise RuntimeError("secp256k1 error")
compact_sig = ffi.new('unsigned char[%d]' % 64)
r = secp256k1.secp256k1_ecdsa_signature_serialize_compact(ECDSA_CONTEXT_VERIFY,
                                                          compact_sig,
                                                          raw_sig)
if not r:
    raise RuntimeError("secp256k1 error")

recover_sig = ffi.new('secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature *')
t = secp256k1.secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature_parse_compact(
                                        ECDSA_CONTEXT_ALL, recover_sig, compact_sig, rec_id)
if not r:
    raise RuntimeError("secp256k1 error")

pubkey_ptr = ffi.new('secp256k1_pubkey *')
t = secp256k1.secp256k1_ecdsa_recover(
             ECDSA_CONTEXT_ALL, pubkey_ptr, recover_sig, messsage)
len_key = 33 if compressed else 65
pubkey = ffi.new('char [%d]' % len_key)
outlen = ffi.new('size_t *', len_key)
compflag = EC_COMPRESSED if compressed else EC_UNCOMPRESSED
if bytes(ffi.buffer(pubkey_ptr.data, 64)) == b"\x00" * 64:
    return None
r = secp256k1.secp256k1_ec_pubkey_serialize(ECDSA_CONTEXT_VERIFY, pubkey, outlen, pubkey_ptr, compflag)
if not r:
    raise RuntimeError("secp256k1 error")
pub = bytes(ffi.buffer(pubkey, len_key))
return hexlify(pub).decode() if hex else pub
```

I got correct result for first 2 variants (0,1), and for last 2 always 64 zeros byte string

What is real count 2 or 4  public keys posible  derive  from signature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *usually* derive two public keys. However, sometimes (very rarely), you can get four public keys.

With some details:

- There is an elliptic curve. In Bitcoin, this is [secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1). Each curve point has two coordinates $(X,Y)$; the coordinates are integers modulo a given prime integer $p$ (precisely, $p = 2^{256} - 4294968273$).
- The curve order (number of points on the curve) is an integer $n$, which happens to be prime, and to be very slightly lower than $p$.
- Private key is $x$, a non-zero integer modulo $n$. Public key is $Q = xG$, i.e. multiplication of a conventional generator point $G$ by the private key $x$.
- To sign a message $m$, things go the following way:

  - A random (non-zero) integer $k$ modulo $n$ is generated.
  - The point $kG$ is computed, and its $X$ coordinate (an integer modulo $p$, hence in the $0$ to $p-1$ range) is reduced modulo $n$, thus yielding a value between $0$ and $n-1$. The result is called $r$.
  - The value $s = (h(m)+xr)/k \bmod n$ is computed. $h(m)$ is the hash of the message to sign, with some hash function that yields a sequence of bytes which is interpreted as an integer.
  - The signature is $(r,s)$.

Now suppose that you have a message $m$ and a signature $(r,s)$, and you want to recompute the corresponding public key $Q$. If you somehow obtain the point $P = kG$, then you can compute:
$$ Q = r^{-1} (sP - h(m)G) $$

Thus, if you can get the point $P$, then you can have the public key $Q$. However, you do not have the point $P$. Instead, you have $r$, the $X$ coordinate of the point $P$, reduced modulo $n$.

Since $n$ is very slightly lower than $p$, there can be two values $X$ that match $r$. In general there will be only one, but if $r < p-n$, then there will be two.

For each possible coordinate $X$, there can be two corresponding points. Indeed, points on the curve follow the curve equation:
$$ Y^2 = X^3+7 $$
Thus, if $(X,Y)$ is a point on the curve, then $(X,-Y)$ is also a point on the curve, and has the same coordinate $X$.

Putting all together: from the value $r$ (in the signature), you can have up to two candidates for the $X$ coordinate of $P$, and from each such candidate, you can have up to two matching points. In total, there can be up to *four* curve points $P$ that match the $r$ value from the signature. For each of them, you can compute the corresponding public key $Q$. But note that the case of two possible $X$ coordinates for a single $r$ is very rare; indeed, this will happen randomly with probably about $2^{-128}$, i.e. never in practice (although you might be able to force it with specially crafted data). Thus, you can normally *expect* to recover two public keys, but (at least theoretically) you might get four.

Comment: Note to elliptic curve implementors who've stumbled upon this answer: the recovery formula is slow, and Wikipedia entry from article "ECDSA" provides 2x faster equation.

Comment: I tried your equation of finding Q given P, and that equation does not work for me. Unless I'm doing something incredibly wrong.