# How does ECDSA signature verify work in EOS and ETH/BTC, compare to standard (on text book I mean)

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, cryptocurrency

I have been studing ECDSA signature/verify for a while. By my understanding: the standard ECDSA signature/verify process (which we find on text book) are like below:
[image]
- A sender combines message and its ECC public key (pk), do hash, then using ECC sk (private key) to generate signature; it then append the signature with the message (ECC pk include), send all these to receiver;

- The receiver do ECDSA verify by using the ECC pk, the message and the signature output true or false;

Question1: for EOS signature verify process looks not likely align to a standard ECDSA signature verify above:

A EOS node may need do two kinds of ECDSA signature verify:

1). Check each Tx signature--from code it use a routine naming as get_signature_keys, indicate it recovers the pk? Then follow up by a routine naming as check_authorization (this does not like a real signature verification, I couldn't understand what a "check authorization" means--by all mean it does not like a signature verify);

2). Check a Block's signature, this routine (name as "verify_signee") however, looks likely a real ECDSA signature verify.

Question2: I know BTC/ETH may adopt quite different method as they are PoW so each miner must do signature verification for each Tx inside a block, but as they have much more time (several minutes) than in EOS, they would be using the standard ECDSA verification?

Answer (score 1):

The two questions are somehow related. The answer to your question (2) is no. In BTC/ETH, signature verification is like the first method you mentioned: the verifier extracts the public key from the signature, hash it, and compare the results to the address where the coin comes. If so, the signature is valid.

The main reason why this is used instead of the normal ECDSA verification is that when you verify a signature, you don't have the public key, but only an address that is the hash of the public key. Therefore you cannot verify using the normal procedure. The key recovery procedure is another way to verify signatures without much security loss.

**Edit to add**: The signature is generated using the normal ECDSA signature algorithm. Recovering the public key from a signature is a well-known trick. For example, it is documented in Section 4.1.6 of [SEC 1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf). See also one of the answers for this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49263/how-to-recover-public-from-tx-signaturer-s-and-verify-signature) for a better explanation. Note it is possible to recover two candidate public keys from a signature, but as I said, this is not going to result in much security loss. See the discussion [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/how-does-recovering-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-signature-work).

Now for the "check authorization" part, a transaction in EOS may require authorization from one or more accounts. So the system verifies that the transaction has been signed by all of the necessary signatures to grant the specified authorization.

Then for the block signature verification, in EOS, there are only 21 producers that can generate blocks. Each producer has a producer key. This is the key for signing blocks and identifying themselves. This key cannot sign transactions on EOS, it can only sign blocks. Therefore it cannot transfer or claim EOS. The producer public key is known by parties who verify blocks, thus the normal ECDSA verification is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some follow up question: 1.  "the verifier extracts the public key from the signature, hash it, and compare the results to the address where the coin comes. If so, the signature is valid“ --> this is somewhat I feel not secure at all, as another guy can do the same thing, recover the publick key and generate a "fake transaction" (in which he can use his own signature, but another one's public key's hash etc..)--my understanding is for a public-key algorithm only very a signature you can confirm this is a "true" transaction?

Comment: Question2:  "the system verifies that the transaction has been signed by all of the necessary signatures to grant the specified authorization." I don't understand the motivation of this, also not sure about what kinds of "authorization" check were done. I am not sure if this is something logicly link with ”get_signature_keys“ routine?  Is here signature verify was done or not?  cover the multi-signature as well?

Comment: (1) No that won't happen. From $A$'s signature $sig_{sk_A}(M)$, you can extract $A$'s public key $pk_A$, but not other $B$'s public key $pk_B$ (except a negligible probability). The attack you described will fail because the verification fails $H(pk_A)\ne H(pk_B)$. 
(2) Authorisation is more complex than that, for more information see here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/eos-permission-management-2c0c1634fe39

Comment: I think this could be my confuse come from. I add a chart in question to better explain--As a “standard ECDSA” signature does not contain the sender’s pk. The (message, signature(r,s), pk) must be provided all together by Sender to Verifier for checking the integrity of signature. But for blockchain implementation, public key is embedded inside signature and also recoverable-- I think it shall follow some “trapdoor” characteristic to make sure this is basically a “one-way travel”.. I shall check a wallet’s signature generation process as well, any good material recommended?

Comment: See added text in the answer.

Comment: That is clear enough! Thanks so much！

Comment: BTW, I suppose by using such public key recovery method->hash->compare tricky, the request to computing resource would be much smaller than standard ECDSA signature verification? It looks some a standard ECDSA verification may take few ms on modern computer, do you know how much resource would be reduced (hence timing consume can be reduced).

Comment: Not really. The main cost of ECDSA verification comes from two scalar multiplication operations. To recover a public key you need two scalar multiplication operations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for help from @Changyu Dong.

Here I'd like to put another chart to show my understand to a EOS based ECDSA Tx sign and verify process.. 
If anything not right please just correct and further discuss is welcome..

[image]

The EOS client signing process refer to a lot from here:
https://eosforce.github.io/Documentation/#/zh-cn/eosforce_client_develop_guild?id=_3-%e4%ba%a4%e6%98%93

Comment: Correct. The details are a little different, but all Bitcoin-like blockchains follow same process to this.

Comment: @conr2d does EOS/ETH/BTC signer (usually the wallet) always generate the recovery id (v) for making the verifier working easier? otherwise verifier has to do up to 4 times (or usually 1~2 times, each 50% chance) guess to find the correct public key by comparing the address. Furthermore what is the initial purpose for doing that rather than simply disclosing the public key directly? To making the hacking effort a little harder? or reduce the transaction size?